# Rails: Get devise to direct to a different page on log in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I've changed the order of logging into a Rails project and I'd like it to direct to a different page after signing up or signing in. 
I'm using devise. The sign in/sign up process works fine - I just want to change the page that users are directed to.
At the moment, signing in directs to home/index.html.erb but I can't find where that is set. There's no path indicated on the submit button in devise/registrations/new.
Can anyone tell me in which file I can set the page where users are directed when they sign in or sign up?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

Comment: Well, that worked! Does this count as a correct answer?

Comment: well no. To count as a correct answer the green tick has to be marked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect to different page after sign in by creating an after_sign_in_path_for method in your ApplicationController and have it return the path for the page you want:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 [Path]
end
```

Comment: Yes, also as Suarabh suggested, this works. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Can I also ask, other than repeatedly posting questions on SO, how would I find this information? The Rails docs doesn't list 'after_sign_in_path_for' as a method for ApplicationController OR ActionController; Are the docs not up-to-date?

Comment: I didnt get you point, but the rails doc are almost up to date

Comment: Well the method was of devise so you should have been looking it in wiki of devise. Also its ok to ask questions if you don't get the answers through a quick google :-)

Comment: I just mean learning Rails, it seems very esoteric and not particularly intuitive. Without asking this question on Stackoverflow, what would be the best way to glean these very specific pieces of information, if the docs don't list ALL the available methods?

Comment: Oh man, really? That seems like it doesn't make sense. I've added the code to ApplicationController, but it's a Devise method? Wacky. (and, no doubt, correct). Thanks for yet another clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Well just writing my answer from the comment which should work.

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
protected
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    signed_in_root_path(resource)
  end
end
```